# Tensorflow keras, shuffle not shuffling sample_weight?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have a sample weight array I am feeding in to fit().  It is of equal size to the number of training examples in my input.  If I turn my learning rate to zero and train for a number of epochs, I see different loss results for each epoch.  If I turn shuffle=False, results stays constant and match the result from evaluate.  It appears to me that the sample weight array must not be getting shuffled.  This is with tensorflow.keras. I assume this is not the expected behavior.  Is it a known bug, or might I be interpreting what I am seeing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `Shuffle=True` and also it shuffles only the training data and not the [validation data](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#is-the-data-shuffled-during-training).

If you want to explicitly shuffle the weights in keras you can use [this](https://gist.github.com/jkleint/eb6dc49c861a1c21b612b568dd188668)

Comment: My concern is that the weights are not following the examples when shuffle=True.  I can't think of a use case where a person would want the sample weights to be random with respect to the samples/examples, but that seems to be the behavior I am seeing.  The examples are shuffled, but the sample weight vector maintains its order.

Comment: This answer does not relate at all to @Mastiff's original question.